# Can I ask generic questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Something along the lines of "I have seen this feature in this one language, do any of you guys know whether something similar exists in *this* language?"

I have been voted down before for asking questions of this nature.

Comment: The title contains "generic questions" and the linked question is about "too specific questions". :)

Comment: I do not think this question is a duplicate of "With all these points in mind, is there, or could be there, a place to ask open-ended questions?" (in the other question). Nowhere is it specified that "I have seen this feature in..." is a too specific or open ended question.

Answer (score 3):

This type of questions is ontopic, but just make sure the question is well researched and useful (to others) to avoid downvoting. Also make sure the desired feature is concisely and completely explained.

Example: [Is there something similar to @import in CSS in JavaScript that allows you to include a JavaScript file inside another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) is extremely highly voted (1804 upvotes) although it shows no research at all. But it is very useful.

This is an outstanding example. Your question will likely be less useful. So make sure it is well researched and well presented to get well received.